# Prove standard cauchy distribution isn't part of exponential family.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, exponential-distribution

So the density is:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$$

and I am supposed to prove this standard Cauchy distribution isn't part of the exponential family. I assume the best way to go about this would be to show a contradiction via one of the properties of members of the family but I haven't been able to do that.

Would appreciate a push in the right direction!

Comment: exponential families can't have fat tails.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I wasn't aware of fat tails. Was able to prove that the standard Cauchy distribution has fat tails but not sure how I should go about proving that exponential families can not have them.

Comment: If you can prove that the coarsest sufficient statistic for the median grows as the size of an i.i.d. sample grows, and if you also know that with exponential families that doesn't happen, then the desired result follows. The former fact is proved somewhere in Bernard Lindgren's theory-of-statistics book (at least in its last edition), but I seem to recall having trouble finding it by using the index.